# detecting unique lines from log file

Tags: command-line, logs, wildcards, text

I have a large log file and would like to detect the patterns instead of specific lines.

for example:

```
/path/messages-20181116:11/15/2018 14:23:05.159|worker001|clusterm|I|userx deleted job 5018
/path/messages-20181116:11/15/2018 14:41:25.662|worker001|clusterm|I|userx deleted job 4895
/path/messages-20181116:11/15/2018 14:41:25.673|worker000|clusterm|I|userx deleted job 4890
/path/messages-20181116:11/15/2018 14:41:25.681|worker000|clusterm|I|userx deleted job 4889
11/09/2018 06:18:55.115|scheduler000|clusterm|P|PROF: job profiling(low job) of 9473507.1 
11/09/2018 06:18:55.118|scheduler000|clusterm|P|PROF: job profiling(low job) of 9473507.1                
11/09/2018 06:18:55.120|scheduler000|clusterm|P|PROF: job profiling(low job) of 9473507.1                
11/09/2018 06:18:55.140|scheduler000|clusterm|P|PROF: job dispatching took 5.005 s (10 fast)             
11/09/2018 06:18:55.143|scheduler000|clusterm|P|PROF: dispatched 1 job(s)             
11/09/2018 06:18:55.143|scheduler000|clusterm|P|PROF: dispatched 5 job(s)             
11/09/2018 06:18:55.143|scheduler000|clusterm|P|PROF: dispatched 3 job(s)             
11/09/2018 06:18:55.145|scheduler000|clusterm|P|PROF: parallel matching   14  0438 107668                 
11/09/2018 06:18:55.148|scheduler000|clusterm|P|PROF: sequential matching  9  0261   8203               
11/09/2018 06:18:55.561|scheduler000|clusterm|P|PROF(1776285440): job sorting :wc =0.006s              
11/09/2018 06:18:55.564|scheduler000|clusterm|P|PROF(1776285440): job dispatching: wc=5.005              
11/09/2018 06:18:55.561|scheduler000|clusterm|P|PROF(1776285440): job sorting : wc=0.006s
11/09/2018 06:18:55.564|scheduler000|clusterm|P|PROF(1776285440): job dispatching: wc =0.015
```

becomes something like below:

```
/path/messages-*NUMBER*:*DATE* *TIME*|worker001|clusterm|I|userx deleted job *NUMBER*
*DATE* *TIME*|scheduler*NUMBER*|clusterm|P|PROF: job profiling(low job) of *NUMBER* 
*DATE* *TIME*|scheduler*NUMBER*|clusterm|P|PROF: job dispatching took *NUMBER* s (*NUMBER* fast)             
*DATE* *TIME*|scheduler*NUMBER*|clusterm|P|PROF: dispatched *NUMBER* job(s)             
*DATE* *TIME*|scheduler*NUMBER*|clusterm|P|PROF: parallel matching   *NUMBER*  *NUMBER* *NUMBER*                 
*DATE* *TIME*|scheduler*NUMBER*|clusterm|P|PROF: sequential matching  *NUMBER*  *NUMBER*   *NUMBER*               
*DATE* *TIME*|scheduler*NUMBER*|clusterm|P|PROF(*NUMBER*): job sorting :wc =*NUMBER*s              
*DATE* *TIME*|scheduler*NUMBER*|clusterm|P|PROF(*NUMBER*): job dispatching: wc=*NUMBER*
```

which greatly reduce the number of lines and make analyzing/reading log by eye easier.

basically detecting variable words and replace them with some symbol.

Comment: What steps have you tried to take on your own? What were the results? Please include this in your question.

Comment: have you looked at `cut` and `uniq`?

Comment: Uniq will only work with exactly matching lines. Will not work for two same line with different time stamp. Cut you need to read the whole log file and yet you don’t know the patterns

Comment: I do used sort -u | uniq but this shows equal lines as if two lines only differ in time stamp both will be printed.

Comment: I don't understand the transformations you're expecting. Do you want the dates and times replaced by `*DATE* *TIME*` or are those placeholders for real values of some sort? What makes a line non-unique?

Comment: it is basically replacing variable words with some kind of category. for example: two lines below should be reduced to one line: `/path/messages-20181116:11/15/2018 14:23:05.159|worker001|clusterm|I|userx deleted job 5018`
`/path/messages-20181116:11/15/2018 14:41:25.662|worker001|clusterm|I|userx deleted job  4895`                               becomes:                         ` /path/messages-*NUMBER*:*DATE* *TIME*|worker001|clusterm|I|userx deleted job *NUMBER*`

Answer (score 0):

How far would

```
sed -r 's~([0-9]{2}/){2}[0-9]{4}~*DATE*~g; s/[0-9:.]{12}/*TIME*/g; s/[0-9.]+/*NUMBER*/g; s/[   ]*$//; ' file4 | uniq 
/path/messages-*NUMBER*:*DATE* *TIME*|worker*NUMBER*|clusterm|I|userx deleted job *NUMBER*
*DATE* *TIME*|scheduler*NUMBER*|clusterm|P|PROF: job profiling(low job) of *NUMBER*
*DATE* *TIME*|scheduler*NUMBER*|clusterm|P|PROF: job dispatching took *NUMBER* s (*NUMBER* fast)
*DATE* *TIME*|scheduler*NUMBER*|clusterm|P|PROF: dispatched *NUMBER* job(s)
*DATE* *TIME*|scheduler*NUMBER*|clusterm|P|PROF: parallel matching   *NUMBER*  *NUMBER* *NUMBER*
*DATE* *TIME*|scheduler*NUMBER*|clusterm|P|PROF: sequential matching  *NUMBER*  *NUMBER*   *NUMBER*
*DATE* *TIME*|scheduler*NUMBER*|clusterm|P|PROF(*NUMBER*): job sorting :wc =*NUMBER*s
*DATE* *TIME*|scheduler*NUMBER*|clusterm|P|PROF(*NUMBER*): job dispatching: wc=*NUMBER*
*DATE* *TIME*|scheduler*NUMBER*|clusterm|P|PROF(*NUMBER*): job sorting : wc=*NUMBER*s
*DATE* *TIME*|scheduler*NUMBER*|clusterm|P|PROF(*NUMBER*): job dispatching: wc =*NUMBER*
```

get you? With some concentration, motivation, patience, and time you could skip the pipe through `uniq` in favour of a complete `sed` solution...